# Prove that $k_{n+1}\in \left\{{Nk_{n}+1,Nk_{n}-1}\right\}$ is not a recursive prime generator

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers, recurrence-relations

For positive $N,k_{0}$ prove that the recurrence relation does not always produce prime numbers (regardless of the recurrence choice).

I have seen this claimed for $N=2$ and the proof thereof is fairly clear: you separate the recurrence choices according to divisibility of $k_{0}$ by 3 and then proceed to compare the remainders of the numbers in the sequence by the prime $k_{0}$. It turns out the mapping from the remainder of $k_{n}$ to the remainder of the following is always injective and because the range of values is finite, the remainders have to repeat, specifically the remainder 0.

I have been wondering however how to prove this holds for other $N$ (I do not believe any would produce a prime generator). The previous approach does not lend itself well to this. I have seen an old contest question claiming it isnt a generator for $N=1986$. How to go about proving this, if not in general, at least for a specific number?

Thank you!

Comment: So at every step you are allowed to make a choice for $k_{n+1}$ out of those two numbers?

Comment: Yes, you are allowed to make a choice, and the task is to prove it doesn't generate for any combination (that is, generate indefinitely)

Comment: @Cellomew An edge case where your statement is not true is $N = 1$ and $k_0 = 1$. In that situation, there's $k_1 = 1(1) + 1 = 2$, $k_2 = 1(2) + 1 = 3$, $k_3 = 1(3) - 1 = 2$, etc. Also, as Peter's comment indicates, I assume your title was supposed to be a set of $2$ values, i.e., $\{Nk_n - 1, Nk_n + 1\}$. Is that correct?

Comment: @John Omielan Yes, it does not hold for N=1, I forgot to mention it in the question. Thank you.

Comment: For $N=1986$, which contest question is this?

Comment: @Bart Michels I have not found it online, it was in an old problems book and got me thinking about this. It did not contain the solutions nor any hints though

Comment: Thanks. Do you remember which book, or the author? Just so we have a reference for the claim that it is true for 1986.

Comment: Can you work out the proof for $N=2$ ? That would surely be helpful.

Comment: @Peter from some point on $k_n > 3$ and then there is only one choice of $k_{n+1}$ depending on $k_n$ mod 3, and you see that the sequence is constant mod 3 and that the recurrence relation is just linear.

Comment: @Peter Yes, specifically for $k_{0}=1 mod3$, $k_{n+1}=2k_{n}-1$ and the other choice for $k_{0}=2 mod3$. Then you work out each case separately. The mapping from the $k_{0}$-remainder of a number in the sequence and the following one can be proven to be injective and because the set of remainders is finite they have to repeat, so specifically the remainder 0 has to occur at some point, meaning the number is divisible by the prime $k_{0}$

Comment: OK, I see now. Actually, for $N=2$ and $k_0>3$ prime, we immediately have only one possible choice since the choice not leading to a multiple of $3$ does not change the remainder mod $3$. Hence we actually only have one relation. This is what I missed.